# Get row number if 3 column values are below or equal to 3 other values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this data in excel and the 3 inputs on cells F2, G2 and H2.
I want to get the row number and in this example it would be **9**.

What I need is to check the row where the following 3 conditions are true:

- values in B are equal or minor than F2
- values in C are equal or minor than G2
- values in D are equal or minor than H2

I found some examples but in my case the numbers repeat itself so I didn't manage to solve it.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Why `9` and not `2` which matches the criteria also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(A2:A12)/((B2:B12<=F2)*(C2:C12<=G2)*(D2:D12<=H2)),1)
```

[image]

---

Since you are looking at dates and you probably want the last date before the dates in the green cells I would use this:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($A$2:$A$12)/(Date(H2,G2,F2)>=DATE($D$2:$D$12,$C$2:$C$12,$B$2:$B$12)),1))
```

Comment: Returns always 7... In case of F2=17, it should return 9.

Comment: @zephirus it returns `9` for me.

Comment: My bad. Some of my data was not really a number but a formula what gets me to the next question. If my 3 columns are numbers your formula works fine but because I get the values from some formulas I always get an error - #NUM! - is there any way I can overcome this? Or I have to format it manually?

Comment: What are the other formulas and why are they not bringing back numbers?  I would look to those and figure out how to bring back numbers and not strings.

Comment: For example, for B2: =MID(A2;SEARCH(" ";A2)+1;SEARCH(" ";A2;SEARCH(" ";A2)+1)-SEARCH(" ";A2)-1)

Comment: put `--` in front of the MID: `=--MID(...` it will change the string to numbers. @zephirus

Comment: Thanks! I also tried to put the formula inside INT() and it works well too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137171/discussion-between-zephirus-and-scott-craner).

Answer (score 0):

So your formula would be:

```
=MATCH(F2&G2&H2,B2:B12&C2:C12&D2:D12,1)+1
```

As this is an array formula you should apply it with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`

Comment: Thanks zipa but that gives me an error - #N/A. Remember that 17 is not in column B.

Comment: @zipa - I believe the OP wants the row number on the worksheet not *within* `B2:B13&C2:C13&D2:D13` which starts on row 2. You would need to add 1 to make up for row 1 not being included in `B2:B13&C2:C13&D2:D13`.

Comment: Did you use ctrl + shift + enter to apply formula? @Jeeped OP wants 9 and that is relative position of his lookup

Comment: @zipa - No, the **actual** worksheet row number is 9. The **relative** row number within `B2:B13` is 8.

Comment: @Jeeped yes, that happens when data is image. Thanks